# Pass Vector by Reference Then Call Clear

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, pass-by-reference, ownership

I am curious if I have been dealing with undefined behavior when clearing the `data_received` vector in client.cpp after passing by reference? I have never had problems with invalid data *but I can see where this might be an issue* lurking. The `vector` is being passed by reference all the way to the final queue - meanwhile another thread will be dequeing at its own rate only after `queue_event.notify_all()` fires.

If this is an issue I believe a solution could be moving the clear just after the *blocking* client->receive call. Thoughts?

**blocking_queue.h**

```
template <typename T>
class BlockingQueue {
    ...
    std::queue<T> queue;
    ...
};
```

**blocking_queue.cpp**

```
template <class T>
void BlockingQueue<T>::enqueue(T const &item)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk (queue_lock);
    queue.push(item);
    lk.unlock();
    queue_event.notify_all(); 
}

template <class T>
T BlockingQueue<T>::dequeue()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk (queue_lock);
    if(queue_event.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::milliseconds(dequeue_timeout))  == std::cv_status::no_timeout)
    {
        T rval = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
        return rval;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("dequeue timeout");
    }
}
```

**client.cpp**

```
void Client::read_from_server()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> data_received;

    while(run)
    {
        if (client->is_connected())
        {   
            uint8_t buf[MAX_SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int returned;

            memset(buf, 0, MAX_SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE);
            returned = client->receive(client->get_socket_descriptor(), buf, MAX_SERVER_BUFFER_SIZE);
            // should probably move data_received.clear() to here!!
            if (returned > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < returned; i++)
                {
                    data_received.push_back(buf[i]);
                }

                if (incoming_queue)
                {
                    incoming_queue->enqueue(data_received);
                }

                data_received.clear();
            }
            else
            {
                client->set_connected(false);
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any potential UB due to `data_received.clear();` because the `std::queue<T> queue;` will hold copies of the passed items (vectors) when `incoming_queue->enqueue(data_received);` is called.

If the access to the queue is well synchronized, which seems to be the case, then the code should be safe.

Comment: ahhh is that what `const` is for in void std::queue push (const value_type& val);?

Comment: @atomSmasher it's not really about `const` ness. It is is stated clearly that with `push_back` [The new element is initialized as a copy of value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back) (or as a move copy if value is temporay or the compiler is sure that state of the value is non longer needed). In your case `T` is a `vector<uint8_t>` so it will be copied or moved, in either case clearing it afterwards won't be any problem. In fact any `container<T>` when passed a `T` will make a copy or a move of the passed T. You should only worry when `T` is a pointer type.

Comment: wow. you are correct. there it is; plain as day. I guess I need new glasses.